# How to prevent html form from being re-submitted after alert box "OK" is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**It's actually a big form this is one field**

```
<form class="bmlf-form needs-validation" method="POST" novalidate>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactPhone" name="ContactPhone" required>
 <button type="submit" class="orange marketing-button bmlf-submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

This form when submitted calls an api and does something. Functionality wise everything is working. Once the form is submitted an alert box is shown to the user saying **"Thank You"** with an **"OK"** button in the Thank You Alert box. The issue is After the user hits Ok in the alert box the form is getting resubmitted again and the form validations are invoking automatically. The alert box Ok is behaving as if i am clicking on form Submit Button without entering any data. I just need the page to be refreshed after i hit ok in the alert box.

I am making an ajax call so my form jquery has prevent.default() as well and also has reset function on my form to reset all fields after the form is submitted.

**Jquery Submit Button Code**

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
$(".bmlf-form").on("submit", event => {

    // Trimming input data to eliminate white spaces
    var allInputs = $(":input");
    allInputs.each(function () {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    const values = $(event.target).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: `apiURL`,
        type: 'Post',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(objectifyForm(values)),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Thank you");
            $(".bmlf-form")[0].reset();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Please try again");
        }
    });
});
```

});

**Form.js Code**

```
 (function () {
window.addEventListener(
    "load",
    () => {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, form => {
            form.addEventListener(
                "submit",
                event => {
                    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    form.classList.add("was-validated");
                },
                false
            );
        });
    },
    false
);
```

})();

Comment: _"Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."_ [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added the Jquery Code as well

Comment: Have you tried to use `event.stopPropagation();` as well after `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Yes its there in my form.js code. Added it now here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. first i would add an ID value to your button, lets say id='submitButton'.

Then when your on-submit function is going off, you can add a line of jquery like this

```
$("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

That will set the button so its disabled, not only preventing further clicking, but giving the user some indication that his click was successful.